# Previews in markup editors

Tags: gui-design, editor

I have seen different approaches to previews in non-WYSIWYG editors.

One is to have a **edit and preview screen side-by-side** or like here on stackexchange the preview below the editor.

And the other one only shows **edit or preview, never both** at the same time.

**What influences do they have on the UX?**

**Is it just that I should use the second one on smaller devices and the first one if I got enough screen estate?**

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid having a separate preview page

Guessing and checking is a cumbersome approach to user input.  Nobody likes being surprised after hitting a preview button only to have to go back and figure out where the mistake is in the markup.

Even if the screen is small I would prefer scrolling down and back up without going to a separate view the way stack exchange works.

The one possible time where having a separate preview page might make sense is if the target device isn't able to handle continuous processing of live preview updates making it impossible to input markup.

Comment: Probably you need to edit your title, "Avoid having a separate preview page at all costs" is not right. I mean, I LOVE "side by side" editors or "below preview" editors and I use them, however that is not "exclusive" to have an standalone preview feature to visualize in a total real environment how your end edition would look like. A perfect "preview" system would have a realtime preview in edition and a small link to "standalone preview". As a user I should have both options.